# Ruby app crashing when it used work just fine (heroku logs posted)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I was able to access the website this morning but I'm suddenly getting an Application Error.

I ran heroku restart but that did not solve anything.

Anyone know what is causing it to crash? And why do I see two IP addresses? I know who the other IP belongs to but I'm fairly certain that he isn't looking at the site. I'm the one who starts with 75 and the other is the one that starts with 64.

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myapp>heroku logs
2013-03-21T20:52:08+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/applic
ation-2fc6a05b812117a44c9ad81d589996e4.css host=www.myapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx"
 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=4ms connect=4ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-03-21T20:54:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 64.xx.xxx.xxx at 2013-
03-21 20:54:26 +0000
2013-03-21T20:54:26+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-21T20:54:26+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-21T20:54:56+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeou
t" method=GET path=/ host=boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="64.xx.xxx.xxx"
 dyno=web.1 queue=0ms wait=12ms connect=9ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-03-21T20:54:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home a
s HTML
2013-03-21T20:54:56+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico h
ost=boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="64.xx.xxx.xxx" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wa
it=2ms connect=9ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=1150
2013-03-21T21:01:46+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeou
t" method=GET path=/ host=www.myapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 queue=0ms
wait=0ms connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-03-21T21:02:20+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeou
t" method=GET path=/ host=www.myapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 queue=0ms
wait=0ms connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-03-21T21:03:38+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeou
t" method=GET path=/ host=www.myapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 queue=0ms
wait=3ms connect=7ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-03-21T21:04:50+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeou
t" method=GET path=/ host=boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx"
dyno=web.1 queue=0ms wait=0ms connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2013-03-21T21:04:51+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico h
ost=boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wai
t=0ms connect=2ms service=79ms status=200 bytes=1150
2013-03-21T21:05:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-03-21T21:05:15+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-03-21T21:05:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
.rb:90:in `select'
2013-03-21T21:05:16+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-03-21 21:05:16] ERROR SignalExceptio
n: SIGTERM
2013-03-21T21:05:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle e
xec rails server -p 25301`
2013-03-21T21:05:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKI
LL
2013-03-21T21:05:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least on
e process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-03-21T21:05:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-03-21T21:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-st
yle plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rail
s 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your ap
p as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes f
or more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been
-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-21T21:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-st
yle plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rail
s 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your ap
p as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes f
or more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been
-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-21T21:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-st
yle plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rail
s 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your ap
p as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes f
or more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been
-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-21T21:05:45+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-st
yle plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rail
s 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your ap
p as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes f
or more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been
-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:         SECURITY WARNING: No secret option
 provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:         This poses a security threat. It i
s strongly recommended that you
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:         provide a secret to prevent exploi
ts that may be possible from crafted
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:         cookies. This will not be supporte
d in future versions of Rack, and
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:         future versions will even invalida
te your existing user cookies.
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:         Called from: /app/vendor/bundle/ru
by/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_s
tore.rb:28:in `initialize'.
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   Is the server running on host "ec2-23-21
-105-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activer
ecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in
`initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PGError)
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1
194:in `new'
2013-03-21
T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.3 application starting in pro
duction on http://0.0.0.0:25301
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:2
8:in `postgresql_connection'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1
194:in `connect'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:2
8:in `new'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
l.rb:313:in `checkout_new_connection'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
l.rb:303:in `new_connection'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
l.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
l.rb:232:in `block in checkout'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
l.rb:232:in `loop'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
l.rb:229:in `checkout'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
l.rb:95:in `connection'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_spe
cification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_spe
cification.rb:142:in `connection'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:3
29:in `initialize'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.r
b:201:in `mon_synchronize'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_poo
l.rb:398:in `retrieve_connection'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbac
ks'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <clas
s:Railtie>'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finishe
r>'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<t
op (required)>'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main
>'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__64769039690635
3246__prepare__2495173404169152159__callbacks'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'

2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-03-21T21:05:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-03-21T21:05:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-03-21T21:05:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-03-21T21:05:52+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-03-21T21:06:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-03-21T21:06:41+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" m
ethod=GET path=/ host=www.myapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx" dyno= queue= wait= connec
t= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-03-21T21:09:26+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" m
ethod=GET path=/ host=www.myapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx" dyno= queue= wait= connec
t= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-03-21T21:09:26+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" m
ethod=GET path=/favicon.ico host=www.myapp.com fwd="75.xx.xx.xxx" dyno= queue= w
ait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: `could not connect to server: Connection refused (PGError)` suggests an error connecting to the PostgreSQL database. Have any of the settings changed?

Comment: I didn't touch anything today. I was able to access it this morning and this error came up out of nowhere. Also, why is the other IP address showing up? I find that odd

Answer (score 0):

There was a hardware issue with `ec2-23-21-105-133.compute-1.amazonaws.com` last night; it's been resolved.